# React route: NavBar always on top while navigating around the components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm an absolute biginner with React and I'm experiencing a really (hopefully) simple problem with routes in React (v6).
I have:

- 1 NavBar
- 2 components

I would like to access the two components through the "NavBar menu" using React routes 6 but I'm not able to fix the NavBar at the top. It disappears as soon as I navigate to the component.

I will explain it using an image:
[image]

This is my configuration:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<NavBar />} />
          <Route exact path="/componenta" element={<ComponentA />} />
          <Route exact path="/componentb" element={<ComponentB />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And if you want [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-river-5n6go?file=/src/App.js) you can find the related CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-river-5n6go?file=/src/App.js

How can I properly configure the routes (v6) to get it work correctly? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to render a navbar regardless of route then render it outside the `Routes` component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/componenta" element={<ComponentA />} />
          <Route path="/componentb" element={<ComponentB />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you want to conditionally render the navbar only with specific routes then render it as a layout component that also renders an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            element={(
              <>
                <NavBar />
                <Outlet />
              </>
            )}
          >
            <Route path="/componenta" element={<ComponentA />} />
            <Route path="/componentb" element={<ComponentB />} />
          </Route>
          ... other routes without navbar
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pull `NavBar` outside of `Routes`:

```
<NavBar />
<Routes>
   <Route exact path="/componenta" element={<ComponentA />} />
   <Route exact path="/componentb" element={<ComponentB />} />
</Routes>
```

Then it should render at the top of the app div, and route changes will render the selected component beneath it.